Narrowing down type hints in children
I was wondering if putting tighter constraints on the type hints in child classes is bad practice or not. Consider the following example
from typing import List, Tuple
from abc import abstractmethod


class Foo:
    @abstractmethod
    def print_stuff(self, items: List[str]):
        """print some list."""


class Bar(Foo):
    def print_stuff(self, items: Tuple[str, str]):
        print(f"Items: {items}, always 2.")
        
class Baz(Foo):
    def print_stuff(self, items: Tuple[str, str, str]):
            print(f"Items: {items}, always 3.")


Here the base class expects some list of strings. In Bar the method only allows exactly two strings, and in Baz exactly three. Is this increased restriction bad practice?
Thank you!

Hierarchically speaking, a Baz instance is a Bar is a Foo instance and can be substituted anywhere a Bar or Foo instance would be expected. But it would reject arguments passed to it that a Foo or Bar would accept. That's not very sane usually.

Note that a list of 2 strings is not the same as a tuple of 2 strings, so the possible arguments of Foo.print_stuff() are not a superset of those of Bar.print_stuff().

Okay, but what would be the best way to enforce this? I would like to force child classes to implement print_stuff, but the arguments (or outputs) may differ. Do I refrain from using typing here? Should I remove the abstract method entirely?

You could make Foo generic in this type. It's not an LSP violation to create subclasses parametrized by different types and makes your intent clear: you want a subclass that can do something with items of type T, which is subtype of tuple[str, ...].

You can use the ellipsis dots to indicate the number of arguments in the tuple is variable.  You should avoid using List in your parent class and Tuple in your child class as they are fundamentally different types.
from typing import List, Tuple
from abc import abstractmethod

class Foo:
    @abstractmethod
    def print_stuff(self, items: Tuple[str, ...]):
        """print some list."""

class Bar(Foo):
    def print_stuff(self, items: Tuple[str, str]):
        print(f"Items: {items}, always 2.")
        
class Baz(Foo):
    def print_stuff(self, items: Tuple[str, str, str]):
        print(f"Items: {items}, always 3.")

This is still not great practice as the Bar and Baz return different lengths of tuples which violates Liskov substitution; mypy will probably throw an error.
The real question is: does it have to be a tuple, or is any sequence acceptable?  Then you should use:
from typing import Sequence
from abc import abstractmethod


class Foo:
    @abstractmethod
    def print_stuff(self, items: Sequence[str]):
        """print some list."""

class Bar(Foo):
    def print_stuff(self, items: Sequence[str]):
        print(f"Items: {items}, always 2.")
        
class Baz(Foo):
    def print_stuff(self, items: Sequence[str]):
        print(f"Items: {items}, always 3.")


Thank you :) But is this considered bad practice here? Because I would not be able to swap out Foo children anymore.

correct.  this different return lengths violates the Liskov substitution.

Running mypy (playground) results in these errors:
error: Argument 1 of "print_stuff" is incompatible with supertype "Foo"; supertype defines the argument type as "list[str]"  [override]
note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides

error: Argument 1 of "print_stuff" is incompatible with supertype "Foo"; supertype defines the argument type as "list[str]"  [override]
note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides

As such I would consider it bad practice.
In class inheritance, method parameters types are contravariant, that is, when overriding a method of the base class, if you want to follow the Liskov Substitution Principle, you can widen the parameter type but not narrow it.
For example, this would be possible:
from typing import Tuple
from abc import abstractmethod


class Foo:
    @abstractmethod
    def print_stuff(self, items: Tuple[str, str]):
        """print some pair (always 2 strings)."""


class Bar(Foo):
    def print_stuff(self, items: Tuple[str, int | str]):
        print(f"Items: {items}, always 2, one could be an int.")


class Baz(Foo):
    def print_stuff(self, items: Tuple[str, str] | None):
        print(f"Items: {items}, always 2, or None.")


So if I wanted to adhere to the Liskov principle, I should remove the abstract method entirely? Thank you!

I don't think this has to do with the abstract method, that only means that the method of base class has no implementation and it must be overridden in each child class.

The only reason to override an abstract method is to inherit the interface, but you (OP) aren't doing that here. Foo.print_stuff promises one type, but your implementations require another. Foo.print_stuff may or may not be needed, but Bar and Baz may as well define separate, unrelated functions with different names.
